# LibreOffice SDK, Calc Add-in Java extension: assign function to a new category

Tags: java, libreoffice-calc

I develop a Calc Add-In with huge set of sheet functions. I would like to put them into a new category.

In LibreOffice Calc Java extension, the in `XAddIn` interface has two functions:

- `getProgrammaticCategoryName()` and
- `getDisplayCategoryName()`.

From [Apache](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XAddIn.html) I see that `getProgrammaticCategoryName` must return one of existing categories, while I would like to have a new one. It is not clear if `getDisplayCategoryName` can return a new category. But it is not called anyway, as I can see from logs.

Is it possible to create a new category?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this in #libreoffice-dev IRC channel at freenode, and answer was that `getDisplayCategoryName()` is not used:

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice/2015-August/069581.html